# Get Client IP from http request - when using a proxy and a firewall

Tags: proxy, httprequest, nat, haproxy, request-headers

We have a webapplication that uses haproxy as load balancer between 2 web app servers (tomcats)
We are trying to get the client ip address from one of our controllers.

Problem is that when we try to get the ip we get the ha-proxy ip instead.

so we tried to use (request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For")) 
But we got the ip of the firewall, (nat)

How can we overcome this situation?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you forwarding the Client IP at HAProxy? You should use "option forwardfor" in your configuration to do that.

Comment: Already did, But on the forwarded for header i'm getting the firewall ip instead.